# PHP - exit from IF block

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, exit

How can I exit a `if` block if a certain condition is met?

I tried using `break` but it doesn't work:

```
if($bla): 
  $bla = get_bla();
  if(empty($bla)) break;
  do($bla);
endif;
```

it says: Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in...

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468836/any-way-to-break-if-statement-in-php for more opinions (:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not just turn it around.

```
if($bla): 
  $bla = get_bla();
  if(!empty($bla)) {
    do($bla);
  }
endif;
```

That way it will only run your code if $bla isn't empty.. That's kinda the point with if-statements

Comment: Your answer solves the problem but doesn't answer the question "How can I exit an if block", it worth to note if it's ever possible.

Comment: @rahmanisback Like you say, it solves the problem so I don't really see what's wrong with my answer. If you just look one answer down you'll see that the question is answered. When I posted my answer there were already several posts answering this, so what I did was provide an actual solution. You can't break an if statement and if you ever need to do so you're using it wrong.

Comment: It solved my problem!  I was doing the same thing, trying to exit when I could rearrange.  I see the merit in actually answering the question, but if the question is using an improper method or not practical, it should be noted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 47):

In PHP 5.3 you can use [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php)

```
if($bla): 
   $bla = get_bla();
   if(empty($bla)) goto end;
   do($bla);
endif;
end:
```

But personally I think that's an ugly solution.

Comment: Why ugly? It would be useful in certain situations for sure. Vote up!

Comment: May I ask why the people behind PHP introduced it in 2009? They could have chosen to not introduce it at all. I agree that it feels very DOS-like to me (not in the good way), but it can come in handy for sure.

Comment: It still has a purpose, exiting out of nested loops for example.

Answer (score 15):

You can't break if statements, only loops like for or while.

If this if is in a function, use 'return'.

Answer (score 5):

I cant believe no one have post this solution yet (writing it in my PHP style):

```
if($bla){do{
  $bla = get_bla();
  if(empty($bla)) break;
  do($bla);
}while(false);}
```

Complexity still O(1)

Comment: Wow. But it's still totally perverted... We have goto at our disposal, we can even use an include() and return from there, but we can't just quit the if block...

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
do {

    if($bla) {
        $bla = get_bla();

        if (empty($bla)) {
            break;
        }

        do($bla);
    }

    /* You can do more comparisions here */

} while (0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

You could put the whole thing into a function from which you can `return`.

Otherwise, you'll have to change the logic and include another if block.

```
if($bla): 
  $bla = get_bla();
  if(!empty($bla)): 
   do($bla);
  endif;
endif;
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it helps to have an escape marker in case the code needs to exit between blocks if you don't mind having an if statement in another.

```
$exit = FALSE;

if(!$exit){
    if($data["param1"] == cond1){
        //do something and continue
    }
    else{
        //do something
        $exit = TRUE;
    }
}

if(!$exit){
    if($data["param2"] == cond2){
        //do something and continue
    }
    else{
        //do something
        $exit = TRUE;
    }
}

{...}
```

If you keep placing conditional statements around each block, it will not execute any other blocks after you set $exit to true. You can name the variable $continue and revert its roles if that makes more sense to you.

it works easier if you have no else statements.

```
$exit = FALSE;

if($bla): 
    $bla = get_bla();
    if(empty($bla)) $exit = TRUE;
    if(!$exit)do($bla);
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, we can't leave `if`-block prematurely, but sometimes it's really needed. `break` can be used only inside loops and `switch`-block. But we can place `if` in a loop. So, answer of Marcos Fernandez Ramos is probably the most appropriate. Here is just slightly nicer variant.

```
do if ()
{
  ...
  if () break;
  ...
} while (false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a statement from which you can `break`, you could use a `while` statement:

```
while ($bla) {
    $bla = get_bla();

    if (!$bla) {
        break;
    }

    do($bla);

    // Maybe some more code...

    // Do not forget to break out of the while loop!
    break;
}
```

This is a good way of avoiding many nested `if` statements (which can maybe be avoided in many cases), but do be careful to `break` the loop.

Answer (score 0):

if your condition is a test against a single variable, then the switch statement is a much better solution and you can easily break out:

```
switch ($var_to_check) { // equivalent to if ($var_to_check==$value_against)
    case $value_against:
        ...
        if ($something_wrong) { break; } // early exit from if
        ...
        break; // regular break
    default: // equivalent to else
        ...
} // end of switch (or if)
... // after the tests
```

It only works for single test checks. Has the advantage of handling a bunch of else ifs.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace IF with WHILE and add `break;` at the end of the new while statement and anywhere in middle too.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for the contains of your IF block.
For example

```
if($bla): 
  doSomething();
endif;
```

Then you can simply use RETURN

```
function doSomething() {
    $bla = get_bla();
    if(empty($bla)) return;
    do($bla);
}
```

It's looking more clearly than multiply IF statements