# Any way to break if statement in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any command in PHP to stop executing the current or parent `if` statement, same as `break` or `break(1)` for `switch`/`loop`. For example

```
$arr=array('a','b');
foreach($arr as $val)
{
  break;
  echo "test";
}

echo "finish";
```

in the above code PHP will not do `echo "test";` and will go to `echo "finish";`

I need this for if

```
$a="test";
if("test"==$a)
{
  break;
  echo "yes"; // I don't want this line or lines after to be executed, without using another if
}
echo "finish";
```

I want to `break` the `if` statement above and stop executing `echo "yes";` or such code which is no longer necessary to be executed, there may be or may not be an additional condition, is there way to do this?

Update: Just 2 years after posting this question, I grew up, I learnt how code can be written in small chunks, why nested if's can be a code smell and how to avoid such problems in the first place by writing manageable, small functions.

Comment: @Usman: If there's not a condition, then the `echo` (in your example) will **never** be executed.  So you might as well delete it.

Comment: Isn't `try catch` an option?

Comment: First I thought Tim was just rude... But then I thought he is correct... Why would you have any code behind an unconditional break? Debugging? I like breaking out of for loops with continue; And it would be nice to break up very difficult queries with a "just stop here" command...
```if (condition) { 
  if ( oneothercondition ) stop;  
  if ( yetothercondition ) stop; 
  // go ahead , all is fine
 }```

Comment: @Joeri i don't know Muhhamad's initial ideas why he needed break; But in my case now it's debugging purposes, right. In some cases it would save time. In cases when not being able to add breakpoints' (when not using an IDE and/or have to work on a live site for some reasons, etc.)

Comment: `I don't want this line or lines after to be executed, without using another if` ... then don't type the line of code.  This [mcve] makes no sense.

Answer (score 263):

Sometimes, when developing these "fancy" things are required. If we can break an `if`, a lot of nested `if`s won't be necessary, making the code much more clean and aesthetic.

This sample code illustrates that in certain situations a breaked `if` can be much more suitable than a lot of ugly nested `if`s.

**Ugly code**

```
if(process_x()) {

    /* do a lot of other things */

    if(process_y()) {

         /* do a lot of other things */

         if(process_z()) {

              /* do a lot of other things */
              /* SUCCESS */

         }
         else {

              clean_all_processes();

         }

    }
    else {

         clean_all_processes();

    }

}
else {

    clean_all_processes();

}
```

**Good looking code**

```
do {
  
  if( !process_x() )
    { clean_all_processes();  break; }
  
  /* do a lot of other things */
  
  if( !process_y() )
    { clean_all_processes();  break; }
  
  /* do a lot of other things */
  
  if( !process_z() )
    { clean_all_processes();  break; }
  
  /* do a lot of other things */
  /* SUCCESS */
  
} while (0);
```

As @NiematojakTomasz says, the use of `goto` is an alternative, the bad thing about this is you always need to define the label (point target).

Comment: Great! Sometimes questions are misunderstood due to their deep sense. You got it perfectly, I need clean code to avoid tracking end of `if`

Comment: If you need to do this ... well ... you're doing it wrong and you need to refactor. Readability isn't something you "hack" into your code by abusing language constructs; it's a self-evident byproduct of well-written code.

Comment: @rdlowrey yea, and you can say php currently have no limitations?? blah! if it isn't useful for you, dont use it, so easy like that.

Comment: @iim.hlk Useful != Good practice. Well-written OOP code invalidates the need for this kind of bastardization. PHP language limitations have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @rdlowrey, talk is free, so PLEASE show us an example of "Well-written OOP" to solve OP question :3

Comment: It's as simple as following SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) and using short readable methods. There's no magic to it. Don't confuse educational criticism for personal attacks.

Comment: Don't confuse sample's request to personal attacks... in fact, you are missing something important, not all coding should be OOP, is an insane thing writing simple tasks with the magic* of OOP.

Comment: Even OOP is procedural within the scope of a method, thinking any other way is madness, surly.

Comment: Remove all else and put `clean_all_processes()` at the end.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Not always. Look at Java Lamda Expressions for examples.

Answer (score 116):

Encapsulate your code in a function. You can stop executing a function with `return` at any time.

Comment: I though you wanted an if, not a function ? ;)

Comment: @arnaud576875 if the code is in a function, than you can use return in the if statement, to break the execution.

Comment: A function should have "1 way in" and "1 way out".

Multiple RETURNS is sloppy and error prone.

Comment: @OldManWalter That is only true for returning actual data. However error handling is a common exception to this rule. A throw exception or return false in multiple location are perfectly acceptable without hitting the common pitfalls the "1 way in, 1 way out" mentality is trying to protect against.

Answer (score 48):

proper way to do this :

```
try{
    if( !process_x() ){
        throw new Exception('process_x failed');
    }

    /* do a lot of other things */

    if( !process_y() ){
        throw new Exception('process_y failed');
    }

    /* do a lot of other things */

    if( !process_z() ){
        throw new Exception('process_z failed');
    }

    /* do a lot of other things */
    /* SUCCESS */
}catch(Exception $ex){
    clean_all_processes();
}
```

After reading some of the comments, I realized that exception handling doesn't always makes sense for normal flow control. For normal control flow it is better to use "If else":

```
try{
  if( process_x() && process_y() && process_z() ) {
    // all processes successful
    // do something
  } else {
    //one of the processes failed
    clean_all_processes();
  }
}catch(Exception ex){
  // one of the processes raised an exception
  clean_all_processes();
}
```

You can also save the process return values in variables and then check in the failure/exception blocks which process has failed.

Comment: Exceptions can be usefull in this cases but it seems that you misuse them. Exceptions are exceptional, not for normal program flow. If the fail is exceptional then the process_x-z should throw the exception by itself; clean_all_processes() would be better in a finally-block since it is clean up which must be done anyway.

Comment: I have improved the solution.

Comment: Reason I did not use finally is, it's not supported till php5.5

Answer (score 30):

Because you can **break** out of a do/while loop, let us "**do**" one round. With a **while(false)** at the end, the condition is never true and will not repeat, again.

```
do
{
    $subjectText = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'subject'));
    if(!$subjectText)
    {
        $smallInfo = 'Please give a subject.';
        break;
    }

    $messageText = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message'));
    if(!$messageText)
    {
        $smallInfo = 'Please supply a message.';
        break;
    }
} while(false);
```

Comment: No one says you must use that. It is just an example to "break" out.

Answer (score 20):

[goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php):

> The *goto* operator can be used to jump to another section in the program. The target point is specified by a label followed by a colon, and the instruction is given as *goto* followed by the desired target label. This is not a full unrestricted *goto*. The target label must be within the same file and context, meaning that you cannot jump out of a function or method, nor can you jump into one. You also cannot jump into any sort of loop or switch structure. You may jump out of these, and a common use is to use a *goto* in place of a multi-level *break*...

Comment: Sorry for being consistent. I have referenced php manual page explaining exact usage of mentioned keyword. And even if it's dirty solution it's still correct solution.

Comment: I don't exactly understand how it's not good practice to do so ? It's much more simple than all other solutions ?

Comment: Agreed with Sébastien. In some cases, the goto operator is very useful, and simple.

Comment: Don't worry, programmers will always make you feel you are not coding properly and want we to code like them. This is even more true in php community because we are a bunch of hipster coders and PHP gives us these freedom keywords and the freedom to be so judgmental about how everyone does things. I've used (not extensively) the `goto` keyword in production codes and I've never had troubles.

Comment: A "while" loop with "break" encapsulated within each ''if" condition is nothing else but a fancy way of doing "goto". if($x){break} == if($x){goto elnd_of_loop}. People who make blanket statements that using goto is always a bad code are simply incorrect as in this case the effect is exactly the same and there is nothing dirty about it.

Answer (score 9):

## There exist command: **`goto`**

```
if(smth) {
   .....
   .....
   .....
   .....
   .....
   goto My123;
   .....
   .....


}



My123:
....your code here....
```

**BUT REMEMBER! `goto` should not be ever used anywhere in real-world scripts, as it is a sign of poor code.**

Comment: I have tested this script , the code below goto Area1; will not be executed.

Comment: The "fear" of `goto` is because it seems appealing to inexperienced programmers who can use it in badly-thought-through ways. But `goto` has its valid uses, and it's not correct to write in bold letters that it should never be used.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a do-while(false):

```
    <?php
    do if ($foo)
    {
      // Do something first...

      // Shall we continue with this block, or exit now?
      if ($abort_if_block) break;

      // Continue doing something...

    } while (false);
    ?>
```

as described in http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#90073

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to "break" an if block like you would inside loops.`:(`
So turn your test into a `switch` !

**I wonder why nobody encouraged you to use [switch statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) since** (even if you haven't to many test cases)
Do you think it's too verbose?

I would definitely go for it here

```
  switch($a){
    case 'test':
        # do stuff here ...
        if(/* Reason why you may break */){
           break; # this will prevent executing "echo 'yes';" statement
        }
        echo 'yes';  # ...           
        break; # As one may already know, we might always have to break at the end of case to prevent executing following cases instructions.
    # default:
        # something else here  ..
        # break;
  }
```

To me Exceptions are meant to raise errors and not really to control execution flaw.
If the break behaviour you are trying to set is not about unexpected error(s), Exception handling is not the right solution here `:/`.

Comment: Interesting idea but I wouldn't use it for "real" code.

Comment: "real", what do you mean ? `:/`

Comment: @Stphane A late comment, but using a switch in this situation goes against the principle of least astonishment. A switch statement is expected to control selection of data, not to control program flow.

Comment: «_switch_ compares an expression against differents values and execute a specific block of code depending on which value the expression equals to.» Then each block may evaluate subsidiary expressions that in turn may instruct the execution flow to return or skip some instructions … I don't think the switch would go against the least astonishment principle in this very narrowed usecase but, this said, the original context and requirements may indeed require some refactoring.

Answer (score 5):

```
$a = 1;

switch($a) {

  case "1":

    if  ($condition1){
      break;
    }

    if  ($condition2){
      break;
    }

    if  ($condition3){
      break;
    }
}
```

In this way I got what I want.  I use a switch only has a definite case and then use break in case to choose if condition.  The reason why I use the break :  condition1 and condition2 may both satisfy, in that situation only condition1 is applied .IF is selective according the order.

Comment: You don't need variable for this. Just use `switch(true) { case true:`

Comment: `switch(true)` is an antipattern and removes the only possible benefit that the verbose language construct has over other techniques -- "solitary evaluation".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. A solution is to pile if.
The first example is simplistic but...

```
    $a="test";
    if("test"==$a)
    {
        do something
        //break; We remove from your example
        if(comparison) {
            echo "yes";
        }
    }
    echo "finish";
```

Or, you can use [goto](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php).

```
    $a="test";
    if("test"==$a)
    {
        do something
        goto the_end_of_your_func;
        echo "yes";
    }
    the_end_of_your_func:
    echo "finish";
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

But how about:

```
$a="test";
if("test"==$a)
{
  if ($someOtherCondition)
  {
    echo "yes";
  }
}
echo "finish";
```

Comment: Thanks, but, I am looking for a simpler version to this to avoid too many `if` statements

Comment: @Usman: If you have multiple conditions, then you need to check them.  Checking a condition traditionally involves an `if` statement.  I'm not sure how you expect to avoid this.

Comment: The OP explicitly stated that they don't want nested if blocks.  This unexplained snippet could be consolidated as `if ("test" == $a && $someOtherCondition) { echo "yes";}`.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the code that is not supposed to be executed to `else/elseif` branch. I don't really see why would you want to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that no, there isn't a way to break from an `if` statement without completely stopping the execution (via `exit`). Other solutions won't work for me because I can't change the structure of the `if` statement, since I'm injecting code into a plugin, like so:

```php
if ( condition ) {
  // Code and variables I want to use

  // Code I have control over

  // Code I don't want to run
}
// More code I want to use
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question whether that is achievable or not, then yes that is achievable using "goto" operator of php.

But ethically, its not a good practice to use "goto" and of there is any need to use goto then this means that code need to be reconstructed such that requirement of goto can be removed.

According to the sample code you posted above, it can be clearly seen that the code can be reconstructed and the code that is no more required can be either deleted or commented (if possibility is there for use in future).

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=array('test','go for it');
$a='test';
foreach($arr as $val){
  $output = 'test';
  if($val === $a) $output = "";
  echo $output;
}
echo "finish";
```

combining your statements, i think this would give you your wished result.
clean and simple, without having too much statements.

for the ugly and good looking code, my recomandation would be:

```
function myfunction(){
  if( !process_x() || !process_y() || !process_z()) {
    clean_all_processes();  
    return; 
  }
/*do all the stuff you need to do*/
}
```

somewhere in your normal code

```
myfunction();
```

Answer (score -1):

i have a simple solution without lot of changes.
the initial statement is

> I want to break the if statement above and stop executing echo "yes"; or such code which is no longer necessary to be executed, there may be or may not be an additional condition, is there way to do this?

So it seems simple. try code like this:

```
$a="test";
if("test"==$a)
{
  if (1==0){
      echo "yes"; // this line while never be executed. 
      // and can be reexecuted simply by changing if (1==0) to if (1==1) 
  }
}
echo "finish";
```

if you want to try without this code, it's simple. and you can back when you want. another solution is comment blocks.
or simply thinking and try in another separated code and copy paste only the result in your final code.
and if a code is no longer nescessary, in your case, the result can be

```
$a="test";
echo "finish";
```

with this code, the original statement is completely respected
and more readable!

Answer (score -2):

The simple solution is to comment it out.

```
$a="test";
if("test"==$a)
{

  //echo "yes"; //no longer needed - 7/7/2014 - updateded bla bla to do foo
}
```

The added benefit is your not changing your original code and you can date it, initial it and put a reason why.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The break could also be in an if.

Comment: You cant comment in an if statement? Or comment out one? Do you mean use an if to exclude execution? If so what's the point of the break then, isn't that what if statements are for? Just comment that out too.  Sorry, but don't see your point.

Comment: Something like this:

a:if("test" == $a)
{
  ...
  if(...)
    break a;
  ...
}

Answer (score -3):

What about using ternary operator?

```
<?php
 // Example usage for: Ternary Operator
 $action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];
?>
```

Which is identical to this if/else statement:

```
<?php
 if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
   $action = 'default';
 } else {
   $action = $_POST['action'];
 }
?>
```

Comment: In PHP7: `$a = $_POST['action'] ?? 'default';`

Answer (score -3):

To completely stop the rest of the script from running you can just do

exit; //In place of break. The rest of the code will not execute

Answer (score -3):

I'm late to the party but I wanted to contribute. I'm surprised that nobody suggested `exit()`. It's good for testing. I use it all the time and works like charm.

```
$a ='';
$b ='';
if($a == $b){
echo 'Clark Kent is Superman';
exit();
echo 'Clark Kent was never Superman';
}
```

The code will stop at `exit()` and everything after will not run.

**Result**

```
Clark Kent is Superman
```

It works with `foreach()` and `while()` as well. It works anywhere you place it really.

```
foreach($arr as $val)
{
  exit();
  echo "test";
}

echo "finish";
```

**Result**

```
nothing gets printed here.
```

Use it with a `forloop()`

```
for ($x = 2; $x < 12; $x++) {
    echo "Gru has $x minions <br>";
    if($x == 4){
    exit();
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
Gru has 2 minions
Gru has 3 minions
Gru has 4 minions
```

In a normal case scenario

```
$a ='Make hot chocolate great again!';
echo $a;
exit();
$b = 'I eat chocolate and make Charlie at the Factory pay for it.';
```

**Result**

```
Make hot chocolate great again!
```

Comment: The reason this has a lot of downvotes is because the commenter didn't explain well enough. exit() stops the execution of every line of code that comes after it. This can result in unfavorable outcomes. It's best to use exit() when an error has occurred and you do not want the code to continue executing. 

`$my_var = do_work(); //false if error 

if( $my_var === false ){
exit();
}

// Do important tasks with $my_var`

Stack messes up the format of the code im trying to write but should be easy enough to understand

Answer (score -7):

```
$a="test";
if("test"!=$a)
{
echo "yes";                   
}
 else
 {
  echo "finish";
}
```