# PHP clean_all_processes() giving 500 internal error, but still outputs

Tags: php

So my PHP file is meant to check if a variable is null, if so than echo and output, and stop there

Here is that code:

```php
if(is_null($ip)){
  echo "IP is not valid";

  clean_all_processes();
}
```

So when I try to test this script using the insomnia rest client it outputs the "IP is not valid" but also gives a "500 internal server error"

In my error_log file it spits out this every time

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function clean_all_processes()

Note: I am using php 7.3

Comment: You are calling function which does not exist. Maybe you need to include from somewhere. `clean_all_processes()`. Just read your error message.

Comment: Markus Zeller according to this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468836/any-way-to-break-if-statement-in-php/7468870 it is valid. And it was working before I switched servers

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function clean_all_processes()` says it all. **UNDEFINED FUNCTION**. This is not about if/else flow.

Comment: @AndrewSturgis19 There's no built-in `clean_all_processes` function in PHP. It must be a custom one. https://php.net/clean_all_processes

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function called `clean_all_processes()` in PHP. The answer you linked to used it as an example name of a function you could call.

If you want a hard stop of your script use `die()`. This is not recommended! You should structure your code in such a way that you should almost never need to use this approach.

There is no way to break out of `if` statement, because such thing makes no sense. An if statement is already a condition. You either execute the code or don't.