# How can I jump out of the if statement block?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a code like this:

```
if (true) {
    echo 'one ';
    /* I need to jump out of this block */
    echo 'two ';
}
echo 'three ';
```

And here is expected result:

```
one three
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You may find the following questions elsewhere on Stack Overflow helpful: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545769/php-exit-from-if-block; 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468836/any-way-to-break-if-statement-in-php

Comment: I cannot think of a single use case. Have you a useful example? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
do {
  if (true) {
    echo 'one ';
    break;
    echo 'two ';
  }
} while(0);
echo 'three ';
```

Just use the `break` function.
One can prevent deep nesting full of if-else statements in many cases by breaking

Comment: `break` doesn't work inside an `if` block.

Comment: @SunnyPatel fixed it

Comment: Haha, that is one way of doing it. But then again why have all that when `echo 'two';` will never get called? That's some overhead to manage! :P

Comment: @SunnyPatel - I would assume that in practice that the break is conditional.  I imagine that once you have enough "breakout" conditions that it's easier than deep nesting ifs.

Comment: A former mainframe programmer's delight.

Comment: The echos are purely for demonstration, and are placeholders. Of course someone wouldn't actually use this if they only had the two echo statements. But they wouldn't

Answer (score 1):

You can't break out of an `if` block.  There has to be a reason why you'd want to break out there otherwise you'd just remove `echo two` and be done with it.  That being the case, just enclose the rest of the code in another condition so that it only executes when you want it to.

Comment: What about `goto` operator ?

Comment: @stack I believe you just answered your own question. 

<?php
    if (true) {
        echo 'one ';
        goto end;
        echo 'two ';
    }
    end:
    echo 'three ';

Comment: yes that's an option, but my point is that you'd always be doing that based on some sort of condition so either way you'll need another if statement once the condition is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have another `if` statement. You can only escape out of `for`, `while`, and `do-while` loops using the `break` statement.

```
if (true) {
    echo 'one ';
    if (false) {
        echo 'two ';
    }
}
echo 'three ';
```

`goto` statements in general are just bad practice.

[image: XKCD]

Comment: Who said that the author would use goto statements?